# Why, if $X_1,...,X_n$ are pairwise independent, is $\sum_{i=1}^{k} X_i$ independent from $X_{k+1}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be n pairwise independent random variables.
Is $\sum_{i=1}^{k} X_i$ indep. from $X_{k+1}$ for some $1\leq k\lt n$?

[A proof I'm working through implicitly assumes that this is true]

Comment: Yea, they are..

Comment: Can you not trivially pick k=1?

Comment: @E-A the OP likely means for *any* $k$...

Comment: Then it is false and the standard example of "pairwise independent but not jointly indepedent" Bernoulli random variables is a counter-example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $X_1, X_2$ be iid uniform on $\{-1,1\}$, let $X_3=X_1 X_2$.  They are
pairwise independent but $X_1+X_2$ is not independent of $X_3$.  (If $X_1+X_2=0$, for instance, then $X_2=-X_1$ and $P(X_3=-1|X_1+X_2=0)=1,$ for instance.)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Yes, I did; thanks for spotting that; and thanks to Mees for fixing it.